# Opencv: Get all objects from segmented colorful image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

How to get all objects from image i am separating image objects through colors.
There are almost 20 colors in following image. I want to extract all colors and their position in a vector(Vec3b and Rect).

I'm using egbis algorithum for segmentation

[image: Input Image]

Segmented image

[image]

```
Mat src, dst;
  String imageName("/home/pathToImage.jpg" );
  src = imread(imageName,1);
  if(src.rows < 1)
      return -1;
  for(int i=0; i<src.rows; i=i+5)
  {    for(int j=0; j<src.cols; j=j+5)
      {
          Vec3b color = src.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j));
          if(colors.empty())
            {
                colors.push_back(color);
            }
          else{
              bool add = true;
            for(int k=0; k<colors.size(); k++)
            {
                 int     rmin = colors[k].val[0]-5,
                  rmax = colors[k].val[0]+5,
                  gmin = colors[k].val[1]-5,
                  gmax = colors[k].val[1]+5,
                  bmin = colors[k].val[2]-5,
                  bmax = colors[k].val[2]+5;
                if((
                        (color.val[0] >= rmin && color.val[0] <= rmax) &&
                        (color.val[1] >= gmin && color.val[1] <= gmax) &&
                        (color.val[2] >= bmin && color.val[2] <= bmax))

                )
                {
                    add = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if(add)
                colors.push_back(color);

          }
      }
  }
  int size = colors.size();
  for(int i=0; i<colors.size();i++)
  {
      Mat inrangeImage;
      //cv::inRange(src, Scalar(lowBlue, lowGreen, lowRed), Scalar(highBlue, highGreen, highRed), redColorOnly);
      cv::inRange(src, cv::Scalar(colors[i].val[0]-1, colors[i].val[1]-1, colors[i].val[2]-1), cv::Scalar(colors[i].val[0]+1, colors[i].val[1]+1, colors[i].val[2]+1), inrangeImage);
      imwrite("/home/kavtech/Segmentation/1/opencv-wrapper-egbis/images/inrangeImage.jpg",inrangeImage);
  }
  /// Display
  namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow("Image", src );
  waitKey(0);
```

I want to get each color position so that 
i can differentiate object positions. Please Help!

Comment: Please provide the input image and expected output results as well, You dont need to write custom algorithm for segmenting the input image on colors, Opencv has some built in functionalities like `kmeans` to do the same.

Comment: @ZdaR Please see now

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/christofferholmstedt/opencv-wrapper-egbis

Comment: So what you need is to segment the output image again to fetch various colors and respective ROI's

Comment: Yup right @ZdaR

Comment: However I personally won't suggest to recompute the already segmented regions and you must look ways to change the source code of the library you are using, to fit in your needs, But still if you are not able to tweak the source code of library then you may use k-means segmentation

Comment: Since you have uploaded the image in `.jpg` format due to which some colors have been mixed up and new colors are generated, Can you upload it in `.png` format ? as png in lossless format and the original colors would be preserved, Currently your input image has **58660** distinct colors

Answer (score 1):

That's just a trivial data formatting problem. You want to turn a truecolour image with only 20 or so colours into a colour-indexed image.

So simply step through the image, look up the colour in your growing dictionary, and assign and integer 0-20 to each pixel.

Now you can turn the images into binary images simply by saying one colour is set and the rest are clear, and use standard algorithms for fitting rectangles.